# Webpack bundle.js content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I start learning `webpack` , `node` , and `react` and I am bit confused about some basic staff.

Does `webpack` bundle whole `react.js` + my javascript files into one output file, so when deploying to production I don't need to install **node packages** used in project (assuming that they are added to **webpack.config.js** file) ?

If above is right:

- On my server I just need to place **index.html** + output from
  webpack ( **bundle.js**) ? ( In simple scenario) ?
- package.json will be used only on development side ?

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Webpack works is that you specify one or more `entry` points and one or more output files. Webpack then reads the entry point and also traverses through the import / require statements recursively. It then generates final bundle file(s) which includes all the traversed files.

1. Yes, Webpack outputs everything in the the bundle.js file(s). You can configure multiple output bundles. So, you just need HTML and output bundle to deploy the app.
2. The `package.json` specifies the packages upon which the app depends, apart from several other things. While traversing through the entry points, webpack will also include the packages specified in import / require. Function of package.json is to tell npm to install those packages.

Answer (score 3):

You only need index.html and the bundle.js (or any name you gave the file) for the app to work, provided that you are not using any local assets. You don't need to include node modules. Package.json should tell you what to include in your project so that you don't have to include node modules whenever you want to upload your project along with few other decalarations.